# Searching for duplicate rows in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm currently running this SQL statement trying to find duplicate rows in my table.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM `wp_posts` group by(post_content) having COUNT(*) > 1
```

However it is bring back every record in this table.

Can someone help?

Comment: `SELECT post_content , COUNT(*) as cnt  FROM wp_posts group by post_content having cnt > 1` and `post_content` is a  text area if I am not wrong and contains long list of text and hence there is a very less chance rather no chance of having same content in to the table.

Comment: Brilliant, that brought back the records! is there any way you could group by the column called: ID?

Comment: that will always show all the rows since id is unique

Comment: Hey Abhik, I've just realised that SQL is bringing back all of the rows again. It's showing 50k returned, but there is only 50k entries in the table.

Comment: could you please share some sample data into the question ?